# Are the Tox network clients Toxic and μTox compatible?

Tags: instant-messaging

That is, for someone to be able to communicate with me securely and anonymously over the secure Tox network, can one person use Toxic and the other person use μTox?

Comment: // , IT Security Stack Exchange is for Information Security professionals to discuss protecting assets from threats and vulnerabilities. Topics include, but are not limited to:

    web app hardening
    network security
    social engineering, including phishing
    risk management
    policies
    penetration testing
    security tools 

This is a specific question about the compatibility and use of two specific security tools.

Comment: // , Please refer to the "What Topics can I ask About Here" guide: http://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: // , From the github page for Tox: "With the rise of governmental monitoring programs, Tox, a FOSS initiative, aims to be an easy to use, all-in-one communication platform that ensures their users full privacy and secure message delivery."

Comment: // , We can agree that SSH is a shell application focused on security, right? What makes it so that these implementations of the Tox protocol are not message applications focused on security? How would you suggest that I reword this question to fit the rules in the help center?

Comment: you could have also asked over at the Tox project: https://wiki.tox.im/Main_Page or on the subreddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/projecttox/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are capable of speaking the same protocol, and communicating with each other.

Every client listed on https://wiki.tox.im/Client has the ability to speak with each other at the basic level.  In the table at the bottom, you will find a list of clients and the features they support.  When two clients that share a capability talk with each other, they can also use that capability between them.